# How to initialize int array member inside the structure . When I try doing this compiler gives an error

Tags: c

```
struct dev
{
    arr[4];
}  Person1;

int main()
{
    Person1.arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4 };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize the object using initializer.

```
struct dev
{
    int arr[4]; /* add type of elements, or it won't compile */
} Person1 = {
    .arr = {1, 2, 3, 4}
};
```

you can simply write like this in this case (write data to use for initialization in the order the members are declared):

```
struct dev
{
    int arr[4]; /* add type of elements, or it won't compile */
} Person1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding this code:

```
struct dev
{
    arr[4];
}  Person1;

int main()
{
    Person1.arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4 };
}
```

the first problem is that the field `arr[]` in the struct definition must be given a type.  perhaps: `int`.

the second problem is that an initializer can only be done when the variable is declared.

That would result in:

```
struct dev
{
    int arr[4];
}  Person1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

int main()
{
    //Person1.arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4 };
}
```

or much better, separate the struct definition from the struct instance:

```
struct dev
{
    int arr[4]; // << edited
};

struct dev Person1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

int main()
{
    //Person1.arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4 };
}
```

if you really want to set the struct contents in the main() function you could use:

```
struct dev
{
    int arr[4]; // << edited
};

struct dev  Person1;

int main()
{
    Person1.arr[0] = 1;
    Person1.arr[1] = 2;
    Person1.arr[2] = 3;
    Person1.arr[3] = 4;
}
```

Comment: your right, I posted the wrong code I'll edit it now: -- edit completed